# How to reverse number with minus sign

Tags: javascript, node.js

As I mentioned before i want to reverse a number with minus sign

expected output

```
141-
```

my output is

```
-141
```

```
/**
 * @param {number} x
 * @return {boolean}
 */
var isPalindrome = function (x) {

    var reversedNum = parseFloat(x.toString().split('').reverse().join('')) * Math.sign(x);

    return reversedNum;

};

console.log(isPalindrome(-141));
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
const isPalindrome = (x) => {
    const str = new String(x);
    return Array.from(str).reverse().join('');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Taking it step by step:

```js
x = -141
-141.toString() = "-141"
"-141".split('') = ["-","1","4","1"]
["-","1","4","1"].reverse() = ["1","4","1","-"]
["1","4","1","-"].join('') = "141-"
parseFloat("141-") = 141
Math.sign(-141) = -1
141 * -1 = -141
```

If you are attempting to output a `number` type that is serialized as `141-`, that is impossible. If you want a string output, there is no reason to parse as a float as the trailing `-` is ignored. So simply remove the `parseFloat()` and  `* Math.sign(x)`.

However, your JSdoc dictate that the function should return a boolean, and the function is named `isPalindrome`, indicating it should return if the input is the same reversed. In which case I would expect something like:

```js
var isPalindrome = function (x) {

  return x.toString() === [...x.toString()].reverse().join('');

};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const isPalindrome = number => number.toString().split("").reverse().join("")
```

`number = -142`

`toString()` method converts the number to string. `// "-141"`

`split("")` method converts the string to array. `// ["-", "1", "4", "1"]`

`reverse()` method reverse the array. `// ["1", "4", "1", "-"]`

`join("")` method returns the array as a string. `// "141-"`

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Comment: @Tyler2P Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

```
var isPalindrome = function (x) {
    return  x.toString().split("").reverse().join("") 
};
```

You don't need to add `* Math.sign`